# Differentiate between NSURLSessions

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

I have a view controller with several methods that fire `NSURLSession`s.
Each of them handled by the `NSURLDelegate`s, for instance

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

In this case: How do I know of what method/session the received data is a result? I need to handle the received data differently for each method, since they all return different data.

Preferably, I would get the received data just right back into the associated method.

Comment: That's why the session and the dataTask are handed back to you. It's your job to know what sessions and dataTasks you have been using. And you can use different delegates for different tasks, so you could store all the information you need in the delegate.

Comment: OK, so, can I tag a session, or data task? in that case I could do some if/then/else in the delegate, to redirect the results based upon that tag/identifier

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tasks can be compared directly.  If your view controller is the common delegate of multiple tasks, it's perfectly okay to keep a `weak` property for each task and do a direct comparison in the delegate methods.

```
// declare weak taskA and taskB, and assign them:
self.taskA = session.dataTaskWithRequest(...

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
    if dataTask == self.taskA {
        // it's taskA
    } else if dataTask == self.taskB {
        // it's taskB
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks easy. Let me try.

Comment: @Sjakelien, did you try?

Comment: What I ended up doing is the following: I put [task.originalRequest.URL isEqual:@"urlBelongingToRelevantMethod] in - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error. In that way, I didn't have to set properties for each method.

Comment: @Sjakelien - that's a sensible approach when the URL alone is enough to distinguish tasks.  For an APIs that provides distinct requests with the same URLs (say, with different verbs, or request bodies, and so on), you'll want to compare something at the higher level (like the task).

Answer (score -1):

Create a new custom class `MyDelegate` or whatever. Instantiate this class for every session and set the data you need to "push back" the received data. Make it the delegate of the session.

Then every delegate gets its own data and can push it back to wherever it needs using the parameters you gave on instantiation.